# MYSQL GROUP BY clause adding a non GROUP BY column

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table in MySQL and I want to do some group by operation. So here is my table

[image]

The expected result should be the sum of prices group by bag_no but the product_id should be the mainproduct='Y'. So the result should be like this

[image]

I can do the following

```
SELECT bag_no, sum(price) AS total_price 
FROM myTable
GROUP BY bag_no
```

But this will not allow me to add product_id in the table which I also want. How can we do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One canonical way to do this involves joining to a subquery which finds the sums:

```
SELECT
    t1.bag_no,
    t1.product_id,
    t2.total_price
FROM myTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT bag_no, SUM(price) AS total_price
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY bag_no
) t2
    ON t1.bag_no = t2.bag_no
WHERE
    t1.mainproduct = 'Y';
```

With MySQL 8+, which supports analytic functions, we can slightly simplify the above query:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        t1.bag_no,
        t1.product_id,
        SUM(price) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.bag_no) total_price,
        t1.mainproduct
    FROM myTable t1
)

SELECT bag_no, product_id, total_price
FROM cte
WHERE mainproduct = 'Y';
```

Comment: "The expected result should be the sum of prices group by bag_no but the product_id should be the mainproduct='Y'" Shouldn't the `mainproduct = 'Y'` filter not also be in the subquery for the first query? It's looks like the topicstarter is only interested in totalling where `mainproduct='Y'`

Comment: @RaymondNijland No, I disagree.  Check the expected total prices and you will see why I gave the answer above.

Comment: "Check the expected total prices and you will see why I gave the answer " Yes i see now they are also summed where not is `mainproduct='Y' and where they are`, geuss  i focused to much on the sentence above the expected results.

Comment: @RaymondNijland It also threw me for a spin for several minutes :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks I used the MYSQL 8+ option but it is not adding row where mainproduct is not 'Y'

Comment: @muazfaiz Thanks for the edits and feedback.  Next time you post here, please include your sample data as _text_, not as an image.  That would have made it easier for me to test my answer.